# rcleartool: How to find files of specific branch

Tags: branch, clearcase, branching-and-merging, cleartool

I'm new to ClearCase, and I'm in the need to locate files in specific branch. So far, I've created an automatic view using CTE, I cannot use cleartool but I can use rcleartool.

I've tried the following, with no success:

```
rcleartool> find . -type f -branch "brtype(aBranch)" -print
CRCLI2049E Pathname is not within a VOB: "."
CRCLI2133W Skipping ".".
```

(Also I've tried the non-interactive rcleartool, with the same result)

Any thoughts on how to get the files given a branch?

For context: Working on Windows, ClearCase 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must be running [`rcleartool`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.2/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/rcleartool.htm), you should, since your are using an automatic view, mount the VOB using CTE or '`rcleartool mount ...`'.

Then you should go to the view root directory (`R:\<view_tag>\` for an automatic view, after [mapping an automatic view root directory to a drive letter](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/mapping-automatic-view-root-directory-drive-letter)) and check that your see the VOB tag in that folder.
You can '`cd`' into the VOB from that context.

Once you are in the VOB, then and only then you can try your `rcleartool find` command.